# Find an equation for the line $L$ in vector form, how to solve and should cross product be used in this case?

Tags: linear-algebra

Struggling to find a way to solve this, not sure if I should used the cross product the two vectors uxv or an arbitrarily point. Can someone help please solving this.

Consider the vectors $u = [1, 0, 1]$ and $v = [1, 2,−1]$. Let $L$ be the line in $\mathbb R^3$ that passes through the point $(3, -2, 3)$ and is perpendicular to both of the vectors $u$ and $v$. Find an equation for the line $L$ in vector form.

Comment: Begin by using the information provided by "Let L be the line in R 3 that passes through the point (3, -2, 3) and is perpendicular to both of the vectors u and v"...Use equations to represent 2 perp. vectors...form the equations and show where did you not go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector from the origin to (3,-2,3) is [3,-2,3] so $(x,y,z)$ is on the line iff $$[x,y,z]=[3,-2,3]+t (\mathbf u \times \mathbf v)$$ for some $t \in \mathbb R$.